# TclError: unknown option "-pre_load"

Tags: python, tkinter, video-player

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
 
root = tk.Tk()
 
videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
videoplayer.load(r"video1.mp4")
videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
 
videoplayer.play()
```

I want to play one video in python. Whenever I run this code it shows "TclError: unknown option "-pre_load"". What is the reason behind this? Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The preload option was removed from version 2.0.0. Please go through the updated [docs](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/Documentation.md)

Answer (score 1):

As @Fra93 mentioned above, there is not such parameter on the TkinterVideo class. When trying to reproduce the code, removing that option allowed me to run the code without problems.

```
videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True)
```

Comment: It did exist before 2.0.0 version. From 2.0.0 version that option has been removed. It's not recommended to install any version lesser than 2.0.0 as there was a bug that caused huge memory consumption prior to 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into the library source [here](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/tkVideoPlayer/tkvideoplayer.py) and I don't see the pre_load in the options.

```
    def __init__(self, master, scaled: bool = True, consistant_frame_rate: bool = True, keep_aspect: bool = False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TkinterVideo, self).__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
```

From where did you get the example?

Comment: I got this code from here: https://codingshiksha.com/python/python-3-tkinter-script-to-build-advanced-video-player-with-controls-to-play-mp4-video-files-using-tkvideoplayer-library-gui-desktop-app/

Comment: And what happens if you remove such option?

Comment: then video is not being played.

Comment: Then can you share what function gives the error? Like the full output, the traceback